# turndjango class based view dispatch ValueError

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

My view class is like this:

```
class RecoedView(View):
    isbn = None

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.isbn = '9754654323456'
        super(RecordView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('This is get')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('This is post')
```

When i run my view with dispatch method overridden i get rhe following error.

```
ValueError: The view ils.views.RecordView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Why am i getting this. Plese make me understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually return the result of the super call.

```
return super(RecordView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```